# UIDatePicker with 2 Textfields (from/until date)?

Tags: ios, xcode, datepicker

I have a DatePicker. I wanna let the User choose the date and time in "from"textfield (which starts at tomorrow at 9 am) and then a textfield "until" ( which starts 1.5 hours later).

[From TextFiled](http://i42.tinypic.com/r7kb5e.jpg)  [Until TextField](http://i40.tinypic.com/akev06.jpg)

For Example. "From" TextField: 25.04.2012 09:00,  "Until" TextField: 25.04.2012 10:30

Take a look at the picture, which i have uploaded.

Everything works fine so far, but if i click on the "until" textfield the Datepicker did not set the correct Date and Time. He Set 25.04.2012 09:00 instead of 25.04.2012 10:30

My Code so far:

```
ViewDidLoad:

    //Create DatePicker

    self.thePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 152, 325, 300)];
    self.thePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    [thePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(dateChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];


    //Set DatePicker to Tomorrow 9:00 o'clock

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

    NSCalendar *german = [[NSCalendar alloc]          initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    [german setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDateComponents *nowComponents = [german components:NSYearCalendarUnit |  NSWeekCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit| NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:today];

    [nowComponents setDay:[nowComponents day] +1]; 
    [nowComponents setWeek: [nowComponents week]]; 
    [nowComponents setHour:9];
    [nowComponents setMinute:0];
    [nowComponents setSecond:0];

    NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [german dateFromComponents:nowComponents];
    NSDate *pickereinstelldate= beginningOfWeek;

    [self.thePicker setDate:pickereinstelldate];


    //Set DatePicker to correct Format
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"];
    NSString *datum =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.thePicker.date];

    //set the date at textfield "bis" to 1.5 hours later
    NSDate *morgenDate = [beginningOfWeek dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600*1.5];
    NSString  *newdate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:morgenDate];

    //Set the until TextField with the newdate

     tfVon.text=datum;
    tfBis.text=newdate; 


    [self.view addSubview:thePicker];
    self.thePicker.hidden=YES;
    tfVon.inputView=thePicker;
    tfBis.inputView=thePicker;


}
```

The Action function:

```
    -(IBAction)dateChanged
    {
    self.date = [thePicker date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"];
    NSString *datum =[dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.date];
    NSDate *neuesdatum = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:3600*1.5];
    NSString *neuesd = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:neuesdatum];

   //when i click on "From" textfield
    if (dateBOOL==YES)

    {
        tfVon.text=datum;

        tfBis.text=neuesd;

    }
        //when i click on "Until" textfield
        if (dateBOOL==NO) {
        tfBis.text=neuesd;

        }    

}
```

here is where i set my datebool to no:

```
    -(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {


    if (textField==tfVon)
    {

        dateBOOL=YES;
        self.thePicker.hidden=NO;

        return YES;
    }
    if (textField==tfBis)
    {

        dateBOOL=NO;
        self.thePicker.hidden=NO;
        return YES;
    }

    }
   return YES;

    }
```

Is There a way that i can set the DatePicker in "Until" TextField to the correct Time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you, you want the date picker to show the date of the text field user selected.

Since you work with `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, I post code within this method too (but don't you think `textFieldDidBeginEditing` would be a better choice).

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField==tfVon)
    {
        dateBOOL=YES;
    }
    else if (textField==tfBis)
    {
        dateBOOL=NO;
    }
    else
    {
      //?? should not happen
    }
    self.thePicker.hidden=NO; 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy  HH:mm"];
    NSDate *dateOfCurrentTextField = [dateFormatter dateFromString:textField.text];
    [self.picker setDate: dateOfCurrentTextField animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: First thank you for your help. It works perfectly. Hmm i only tried it with textFieldShouldBeginnEditing. How can i use textfieldDidBeginnEditing, because the typ of this method is void.

Comment: textFieldDidBeginEditing is void, because it's called when the user starts editing, which means something told the text field that it is allowed. This can be done be either textFieldShouldBeginEditing implementation (like you did) or by default (if u wouldn't have implemented the method). Ur impl. of textfieldDidBeginnEditing should exactly look like ur impl. of textFieldShouldBeginnEditing except of returning nothing. textFieldShouldBeginnEditing is for programs that decide during runtime (dependent of whatever) if the user is allowed to edit, i.e. they sometimes return YES and sometimes NO.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the explanation. Now i think also that textFieldDidBeginnEditing is the better choice! Again, thx for your help